# How to remove unrequired places from google places API?

Tags: java, android, google-places-api

I've created a google places API for my app, it currently shows all the places nearby like hospitals, restaurants, schools etc. I want it to show only restaurants. Is it possible? If so, how? Help would be much appreciated. Thanks :)

**MapActivity.JAVA**

```
package com.golo.acer.mrestro4;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlacePicker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;


public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;
    private TextView mName;
    private TextView mAddress;
    private TextView mAttributions;
    private static final LatLngBounds BOUNDS_MOUNTAIN_VIEW = new LatLngBounds(
            new LatLng(27.689753, 85.311188), new LatLng(27.689753, 85.311188));

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_place_picker);
        mName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        mAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        mAttributions = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        Button pickerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickerButton);
        pickerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    PlacePicker.IntentBuilder intentBuilder =
                            new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
                    intentBuilder.setLatLngBounds(BOUNDS_MOUNTAIN_VIEW);
                    Intent intent = intentBuilder.build(MapActivity.this);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);

                } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException
                        | GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void moveToInternalChoiceActivity(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, InternalChoiceActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
                                    int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST
                && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            final Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(this, data);
            final CharSequence name = place.getName();
            final CharSequence address = place.getAddress();
            String attributions = (String) place.getAttributions();
            if (attributions == null) {
                attributions = "";
            }

            mName.setText(name);
            mAddress.setText(address);
            mAttributions.setText(Html.fromHtml(attributions));

        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Include your code!

Comment: @khargoosh code included above :)

Answer (score 1):

`place.getPlaceTypes()` returns a list of integer, check if it contains `Place.TYPE_RESTAURANT` if finding the restaurant type is your intention. You can get the type values in the `Place` class, beginning with `TYPE_`.

Ref https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/Place

[Edit] 
In your code :

```
final Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(this, data);
List<Integer> types = place.getPlaceTypes();
for(Integer i : types){
    if (i == Place.TYPE_RESTAURANT){
           // its restaurant do something
        final CharSequence name = place.getName();
        final CharSequence address = place.getAddress();
        String attributions = (String) place.getAttributions();
        if (attributions == null) {
            attributions = "";
        }

        mName.setText(name);
        mAddress.setText(address);
        mAttributions.setText(Html.fromHtml(attributions));
    } 
}
```

[Edit : (comments from user)]

What you are describing as red icon is a marker, you can add them on the map.
so in your `onActivityResult` you get a `Place` (already shown in your code).
Place contains name and position, using that show a marker on the map like this:

```
Marker markerPlace = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(place.getLatLng()).title(place.getName));
```

Check the documentation and related articles for map marker.

Now how to add a Map ?? dont ask me, check for information in the internet
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html#mapsview

Comment: I'm not quite getting what you're saying, can you please edit my code? thanks :)

Comment: it shows error after the if statement. I want to display restaurants only in the places nearby of google places. What should be after the if statement?

Comment: edited the post, obviously spoonfeeding the answer is not possible all times, you should use your sense to modify your existing codes according to the provided information. here the if condition determines if the current place is a restaurant, so inside the if block you should update your UI with the place data.

Comment: the code worked but this is not what I was trying to do. This code extracts information only from restaurants and not from other places. I want to display the red icons for only the restaurants and not others in google places. I cannot find code for this task anywhere on the internet too. any help would be much appreciated thanks :)

Comment: red icons on where ?

Comment: red icons i.e. the place locations; the place marks shown on google places. a knife and fork is shown for restaurants, coffee cup for coffee houses and so on. I only want to display the restaurants icons. Is that possible?

Comment: on map ? or on your existing UI ?

Comment: on the map that gets displayed inside my app.